# In terms of MMA, what is a back kick?

Tags: kicking, mixed-martial-arts

In orthodox stance, I pivot my rear foot and hips to my right, so my back is (almost) facing the target, then fire my front leg with the heel side (mostly) up. Another variation is stepping your lead leg back into south paw first.

When I practice this kick, it feels like I can generate more power than any other move. It's very fast to use and recover from. More so than the `standard back kick` I've seen elsewhere. And I expect it would be useful as a leg kick to the knee or thigh. At least to the point of there being an occasional opportunity for its use. But I have never seen it used in MMA.

Can you explain the technique and usage of this kick in terms of its role in MMA (why isn't it used)? If this isn't named a back kick, what is its name?

Comment: Sounds fine to me. Why don't you go spar with it and see what you find out?

Answer (score 5):

To be honest I'm not really sure how you differentiate what you described from what you term as a "standard back kick". There can be a few ways to execute this kick, most of them are just variations on how to start it. You are quite correct that it is a very effective (and devastating) kick if executed correctly.

But the reason why you never see the back kick used in MMA (and very seldom in other competitions) is because:

1. you have to turn your back on the opponent. This is dangerous any time you have to do it, but especially so in MMA where your opponent is allowed to tackle and follow with extended grapple. Your opponent only has to alter their position a little for the kick to become vastly less effective - if it lands at all. Additionally most practiced MMA contenders don't need much of an opening to attempt a take down, if you turn your back on them you're giving them a free shot at it.
2. remember that MMA tends to be quite BJJ centric. There won't be many competitors in MMA who have trained extensively in a more traditional art (and therefore becoming proficient with the kick) before immersing themselves in MMA (and consequently BJJ). I could name lots of effective techniques that you never see in MMA, simply because the participants don't learn them.

I'd venture that the main reason though is because MMA and BJJ - for good reason - don't value that particular kick highly enough to train in it.